# What is the purpose of finally if it always executes in java?

Tags: java, try-catch-finally

Consider the following Java snippets:

```
try{
   //Some code to tryout
}
catch(Exception e){
   //Catch if there is an exception
}
finally{
   //SNIPPET1 that is always executed
}
```

The above snippet is essentially equal to

```
try{
   //Some code to tryout
}
catch(Exception e){
   //Catch if there is an exception
}
//SNIPPET1 that is always executed
```

I know that **finally** block is usually used to close network connections, file streams etc. I do not see a strong motivation in introducing this keyword into the language because one can happily program without using it as well.

Can you please explain the rationale behind introducing this keyword?

Comment: Think about this: What happens if an exception is thrown in the `catch` block? (In that case there's a difference in behaviour between the two snippets you posted).

Comment: This block allows the programmer to avoid having cleanup code accidentally bypassed by a return, continue, or break. Putting cleanup code in a finally block is always a good practice, even when no exceptions are anticipated.It is also a key tool for preventing resource leaks

Comment: You can also refer java docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

Comment: Sorry for the duplication. Closing the question... Edit: Apparently I couldn't :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
try {
    // statement 1
} catch (Exception e) {
    // statement 2
}
// statement 3
```

statement 3 won't be executed if statement 2 throws an exception